# Does static variable inherited?

Tags: java, static

We know that in java static variable are not inherited. But in below code I am not getting any error as I want to initialize the static variable in child class.

```
class s
{
    static int x;
}

class aaa extends s
{

    void fun()
    {
        x=2;
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        aaa w=new aaa();
        w.fun();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`static` members are most definitely accessible from subclasses, as your example shows. You cannot override them, of course, but you could hide them.

Comment: You can also hide none `static` members